# HTML How to verify if a text box is filled and send the user to another page

Tags: javascript, html

I`ve building a login page and I would like to redirect the user to another html page only if the Html textbox and password were filled (with anything).

My idea is using only Html and Javascript to do it (as far as I don`t need php to send the data).

So here is my html, the forms part specifically

```
<form name="frmTeste" onsubmit="return validaForm(this);">
            <fieldset id="usuario">
                <legend id="usuario" >Identificação do Usuário</legend>
                
                <p>Nº <input type="text" name="tNumero" id="tNumero" size="20" maxlength="15" placeholder="ID"> </p>

                <p><label for="cSenha" >Senha:</label> <input type="password" name="tSenha" id="cSenha" size="20" maxlength="12" placeholder="Senha" autocomplete="current-password"/> </p>
                    
                <input type="submit" id="botao" class="bt bt-acessar" value="Entrar" onclick="Nova(this)">

                <p>
                    Não possui uma conta? <a href="#" id="cadastrar" onclick="alert('Desculpe, ainda não é possível realizar cadastro')"> Cadastrar </a>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

And here is my javascript

```
function validaForm(frm) {
        if(frm.tNumero.value == "" || frm.tNumero.value == null || frm.tNumero.value.lenght < 3) {
            
            alert("Por favor, indique o seu numero USP.");
            
            frm.nome.focus();
            return false;
        }else if(frm.cSenha.value == "" || frm.cSenha.value == null || frm.cSenha.value.lenght < 3){
            alert("Por favor, indique sua senha");

            frm.nome.focus();
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    function Nova(frm){
        if (validaForm(frm) == false){
            location.href = "index.html";
        }else if (validaForm(frm) == true){
            location.href = "notas.html";
        }
```

I`ve trying a lot of different ways but with no sucess at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for.

You should change

```
<form name="frmTeste">
            <fieldset id="usuario">
                <legend id="usuario" >Identificação do Usuário</legend>
                
                <p>Nº <input type="text" name="tNumero" id="tNumero" size="20" maxlength="15" placeholder="ID"> </p>

                <p><label for="cSenha" >Senha:</label> <input type="password" name="tSenha" id="cSenha" size="20" maxlength="12" placeholder="Senha" autocomplete="current-password"/> </p>
                    
                <input type="submit" id="botao" class="bt bt-acessar" value="Entrar" onclick="validateForm(this)">

                <p>
                    Não possui uma conta? <a href="#" id="cadastrar" onclick="alert('Desculpe, ainda não é possível realizar cadastro')"> Cadastrar </a>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Also change the javascript

```
function validateForm(frm){
            window.event.preventDefault();
            frm = frm.parentNode.parentNode;
            var tNumero = document.getElementById("tNumero");
            var cSneha = document.getElementById("cSenha");
            if(tNumero.value.length < 3) {  
                alert("Por favor, indique o seu numero USP.");
                window.location.href = "/index.html";
            } else if(cSenha.value.length < 3){
                alert("Por favor, indique sua senha");
                window.location.href = "/index.html";
            }else{
               frm.setAttribute("action","/notas.html");
               frm.submit();
            }
        }
```